# SQL Join with Order by and Group by

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access-2007, vba

Hi Im trying to do a Join in Excel from another Excelworkbook.

The primary key in the first table is Part_No. This is not the primary key so a 1 to 1 join can't be made.

I want to choose the best Order Status from results matching the LIKE and NOT LIKE keywords.

The WHERE statements works perfectly But the FIRST statements don't seem to match the ORDER BY, the results is some what random. Sometimes I get 'Canceled'-orders when there is a Order of that same Part that is in Stock. I see both rows when only executing the inner Select with the In Stock first.

I'm using `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` for my ADODB Connection in Excel vba.

What is wrong? Thanks for your help!

```
SELECT 
    FIRST(o.Part_No), 
    FIRST(o.Order_Desc),
    FIRST(o.Order_Status)
FROM 
    Parts 
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Orders
        WHERE 
            Orders.Order_Desc Like '%keyword%' AND 
            Orders.Order_Desc Not Like '%otherkeyword%'
        ORDER BY 
            IIF(Orders.Order_Status = 'In Stock' , 1, 
            IIF(Orders.Order_Status = 'In Transit' , 2, 
            IIF(Orders.Order_Status = 'Ordered' , 3, 
            IIF(Orders.Order_Status = 'Canceled' , 4)))) ASC
    ) AS o
    ON Parts.Part_No = o.Part_No
GROUP BY Parts.Part_No;
```

Here is an example.

```
List Parts
Part No
1
2

List Orders
Part No    Order_Desc         Order_Status
1          keyword            In Stock
1          keyword            Canceled
2          keyword            Ordered
2          not keyword        In Stock
2          keyword            Canceled
3          keyword            Ordered
3          keyword            In Stock
3          keyword            In Stock
5          not keyword        In Stock

What i get
1          keyword            Canceled (seems Random right or wrong)
2          keyword            Ordered

Desired Result
1          keyword            In Stock
2          keyword            Ordered
```

Hope that this example helps!
I'm kind of new making posts here. Sorry for the strange tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(o.Part_No), 
FIRST(o.Part_No), 
FIRST(o.Order_Status), 
FIRST(o.Order_No), 
FIRST(o.Order_Desc),
        IIF(Orders.Order_Status = 'In Stock' , 1, 
        IIF(Orders.Order_Status = 'In Transit' , 2, 
        IIF(Orders.Order_Status = 'Ordered' , 3, 
        4))) AS Order_Status_OrderBy

FROM 
Parts 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Orders
    WHERE 
        Orders.Order_Desc Like '%keyword%' AND 
        Orders.Order_Desc Not Like '%otherkeyword%'
    ORDER BY 
        Order_Status_OrderBy
) AS o
ON Parts.Part_No = o.Part_No
GROUP BY Parts.Part_No;
```

Comment: This did not work. I need to do the Order by inside the inner Select or I get 'You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Order_Status_OrderBy' as part of an aggregate function.'

Comment: Add the Order_Status_OrderBy to the GROUP BY

Comment: That results in multiple rows in some results, one for each Order_Status_OrderBy. But still the rows are written in the right order so the Order By works. Just that the FIRST doesn't seem to do its job.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Maybe you can explain with some examples of data so i know what it is you want.